# wrapper table not showing bg image

Tags: html, css

I'm building a html e-mailer and I'm trying to get my wrapper table to display a background image so my inner tables can overlay the text on top of it but its not showing the background image on the wrapper.

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="639" align="left" style="background-image:url(../../images/email-bg.jpg); width:639px; height:489px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#477398 "><h1>This is my title text</h1></td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; padding:10px 0 5px 2px; text-decoration:underline; color:#808184 "><a href="#">Continue</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
```

Comment: What invalid about it? Using tables because it needs to work in old email apps.

Comment: Run it through any HTML validator (e.g. http://validator.w3.org/) and you'll see.

Comment: try an absoulte link to the image versus a relative one.

Comment: I ran it through a validator and I fixed the missing style="" on the first td but this still does not show the image on the background. Even if I use an absolute url. If I take away the wrapper table and set the background style on the inner table it works.

Comment: It could be because your inner table hiding the wrapper table, try removing the inner table and see if you can see the background image.

Comment: Your first table is missing a tr and td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="639" align="left" >
<tr>
<td style="background-image:url(../../images/email-bg.jpg); width:639px; height:489px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#477398 "><h1>This is my title text</h1></td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; padding:10px 0 5px 2px; text-decoration:underline; color:#808184 "><a href="#">Continue</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Please check your first table do not have tr and td elements.

Comment: Where is style in your first `td` ?

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious that `font-family` is not an HTML attribute, and should instead by inside of the `style` attribute.

Comment: his first table were missing tr and td

Comment: And you are missing the style in the first `td`.

Comment: don't forget to give the image an absolute url.